# Failed to integrate the git into Redmine 2.3.2

Tags: git, passenger, redmine

I had install Bitnami Redmine on my Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS. It works well!

But now I want to integrate the git into redmine and follow the offices tutorial [How_to_configure_Redmine_for_advanced_integration_with_Git](http://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/BitNami_Redmine/BitNami_Redmine_legacy#How_to_configure_Redmine_for_advanced_integration_with_Git)

step 3.a is success

and step 4, I copy and add the the script to /usr/local/share/redmine/apache2/conf/httpd.conf and restart redmine

Here is a part of httpd.conf

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/share/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.2/libout/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /usr/local/share/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.2
PassengerRuby /usr/local/share/redmine/ruby/bin/ruby

<VirtualHost *:8088>
   DocumentRoot "/usr/local/share/redmine/apache2/htdocs/grack/public"
<Directory "/usr/local/share/redmine/apache2/htdocs/grack/public">
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and then test on my mac and got the below info

```
Hseecoms-iMac:Githsee itHsee$ git clone http://192.168.100.1:8088/test
Cloning into 'test'...
error: Failed connect to 192.168.100.1:8088; Connection refused while accessing     http://192.168.100.1:8088/test/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Here is the log I got from /usr/local/share/redmine/apache2/log/error_log

```
[Mon Aug 12 14:31:57.349295 2013] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30562] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Aug 12 14:32:01.837475 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 31114] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for localhost:8443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[ 2013-08-12 14:32:01.8552 31118/7f955dfad740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:554 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.31114/generation-0/request.socket
[ 2013-08-12 14:32:01.8643 31124/7f9e8c0c0740 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:272 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.31114/generation-0/logging.socket
[Mon Aug 12 14:32:02.125219 2013] [ssl:warn] [pid 31134] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for localhost:8443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Mon Aug 12 14:32:02.125366 2013] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 31134] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[ 2013-08-12 14:32:02.1594 31138/7fd91d40d740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:554 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.31134/generation-0/request.socket
[ 2013-08-12 14:32:02.1684 31144/7f76267bf740 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:272 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.31134/generation-0/logging.socket
[Mon Aug 12 14:32:02.172329 2013] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31134] AH00163: Apache/2.4.4 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e PHP/5.4.17 Phusion_Passenger/4.0.2 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Aug 12 14:32:02.172398 2013] [core:notice] [pid 31134] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/share/redmine/apache2/bin/httpd -f /usr/local/share/redmine/apache2/conf/httpd.conf'
/usr/local/share/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.2/helper-scripts/prespawn:105:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
    from /usr/local/share/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.2/helper-scripts/prespawn:105:in `new'
    from /usr/local/share/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.2/helper-scripts/prespawn:105:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/share/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.2/helper-scripts/prespawn:86:in `socket'
    from /usr/local/share/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.2/helper-scripts/prespawn:90:in `head_request'
    from /usr/local/share/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.2/helper-scripts/prespawn:145:in `<main>'
/usr/local/share/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.2/helper-scripts/prespawn:105:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
    from /usr/local/share/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.2/helper-scripts/prespawn:105:in `new'
    from /usr/local/share/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.2/helper-scripts/prespawn:105:in `connect'
    from /usr/local/share/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.2/helper-scripts/prespawn:86:in `socket'
    from /usr/local/share/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.2/helper-scripts/prespawn:90:in `head_request'
    from /usr/local/share/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.2/helper-scripts/prespawn:145:in `<main>'
[ 2013-08-12 14:32:05.0932 31138/7fd91d316700 Pool2/Spawner.h:739 ]: [App 31212 stdout] 
[ 2013-08-12 14:32:05.6724 31138/7fd91d2d5700 Pool2/Spawner.h:159 ]: [App 31212 stderr] /usr/local/share/redmine/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:216: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/share/redmine in PATH, mode 040777
[ 2013-08-12 14:32:08.4796 31138/7fd91d316700 Pool2/SmartSpawner.h:300 ]: Preloader for /usr/local/share/redmine/apps/redmine/htdocs started on PID 31212, listening on unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.31134/generation-0/backends/preloader.31212
sysadmin@Hsee:/usr/local/share/redmine/apache2/logs$
```

Does anyone can help me to solve this issue? Many thanks!

Comment: the same fails. Are you solve it ?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know Bitnami, but I've installed Redmine myself on Ubuntu. So I hope my answer will help you in some way.

Are you sure that your Apache server is in this directory: `/usr/local/share/redmine/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` INSIDE your Redmine directory and not something like `/etc/apache2/`?

And are you sure you want to use port: 8088? In the tutorial that you've linked they used 8080 and 80, but not 8088.

I think your Passenger is still not configured correctly. It's been quite a long time that I've done this the last time, but anyway these HowTos helped me:

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_on_Ubuntu_step_by_step#Configuring-Apache
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_Ubuntu
http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_212_in_Ubuntu_1210_and_Apache_Passenger

And this is a self written HowTo to integrate GIT afterwards into Redmine:

http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Easily_integrate_a_%28SSH_secured%29_GIT_repository_into_redmine

Hope this helps